# p:message not rendered

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, xhtml

I'm using an old version of **Primefaces (3.5)** in my project and I'm struggling with a problem for 2 days now. The problem is the following:

I have a template, in which I insert an UI. In this UI, I have a TabView, in which I include an xhtml.

I need to check if some inputText fields, set as required, were left blank after a tab change, and if they were, a message must appear under those fields. For that, I'm using `<p:message>` but it's not working and I can't find the reason. I inspected the page, and found out that the `<p:message>` field is not being rendered... and I've tried everything and googled for solutions, but to no avail.

Any ideas on how to solve this? (check the above example with `<p:message for="test_name" />`)

Thanks!

**Template Code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <f:facet name="first">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></meta>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="#{session.maxInactiveInterval};url=#{disclaimer.currentURLincludingQueryString}"/>
    </f:facet>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"
        href="/alt-ui/resources/images/favicon.ico" />
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="alt.css" />
    <title><ui:insert name="head_title">
            <h:outputText value="ALT" />
            <ui:repeat value="#{breadcrumbBean.breadcrumbList}" var="breadcrumb">
                &#124;<h:outputText value="#{breadcrumb.value}" />
            </ui:repeat>
        </ui:insert>
    </title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<f:view>
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="Common.js" />
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="ModalDialog.js" />

    <div id="main_header">
        <p:graphicImage library="images" name="Logo.png" alt="Logo" />
        <div id="alt_header">
            <h:outputText value="Remote Services" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <h:form id="mainForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        #{disclaimer.checkConfirm()}

        <div id="center">
            <p:messages id="main_msg" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" severity="error, fatal" />
            <ui:insert name="main-content">center</ui:insert>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            <div id="footer_content">
                <ui:insert name="footer-content"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <p:growl id="template_growl" showDetail="false" autoUpdate="true" sticky="true" severity="info, warn"/>

    </h:form>
    </f:view>
</h:body>
</html>
```

**Page XHTML:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ui:composition xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" template="/pages/templates/main_template.xhtml">
  <ui:define name="head_title">
    <h:outputtext value="#{msg['zynx.test.details.title']}" />
  </ui:define>

  <ui:define name="main-content">
    <p:tabview id="test_tabview" styleclass="rustabview" cache="true" binding="#{zynxtestdetails.tabview}" activeindex="#{zynxtestdetails.activeindex}">
      <f:attribute name="enablevalidation" value="#{zynxtestdetails.firsttabchange}" />

      <p:ajax event="tabchange" listener="#{zynxtestdetdetails.ontabchange}" immediate="true" />

      <p:tab id="tabmetadata" title="#{msg['zynx.test.tab.data.heading']}">

        <p:panelgrid columns="1" styleclass="rustabpanel">
          <ui:include src="tabtestdata.xhtml" />
        </p:panelgrid>
      </p:tab>
  </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

**TabTestData.xhtml:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ui:composition xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">


  <p:panelGrid id="dataDefinition" columns="5" columnClasses="alignTop,,,alignTop,alignTop">
    <h:outputText styleClass="ui-widget-header2" value="#{msg['zynx.test.tab.data.headline']}" />
    <p:spacer />
    <p:spacer />
    <p:spacer />
    <p:spacer />


    <p:outputLabel value="#{msg['zynx.test.tab.data.name']}" for="test_name" />
    <p:inputText id="test_name" value="#{dynamicTestData.name}" size="50" required="true" disabled="#{zynxTestDetails.TestActive()}" validator="#{zynxTestDetails.validateName}" onchange="setTestChangedForBackAction()" />
    <p:message for="test_name" />
  </p:panelGrid>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: there is just `<p:messages>` (not `<p:message>`) in PrimeFaces. Did you try to set its `autoUpdate` property to `true`?

Comment: @TheBitman false, `<p:message>` does exist, even in PF 3.5.

Comment: Where do you `update` your messages? Normally you would expect a command button which updates the form.

Comment: The tabchange event of the p:ajax needs to have update="@form" to update the messages after the ajax request

Comment: @JasperdeVries PrimeFaces 6.0 showcase does not contain a component called `message`. But you are right. The PrimeFaces 6.0 Users Guide contains a single reference to it.

Comment: It does: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/message/messages.xhtml

Comment: @JasperdeVries OK. The exapmle contains, but the menu does not.

Comment: Don't rely on the menu. Try to search `SelectOneMenu` for example.

Comment: @OTM "The tabchange event of the p:ajax needs to have update="@form" to update the messages after the ajax request" - is that the reason why the <p:message> is not rendered in the page?

Thanks

Comment: @JasperdeVries "Where do you update your messages? Normally you would expect a command button which updates the form." - The tabChange should do it, but the message element is not rendered... any idea why?


Thanks

Comment: Yes, correct, The p: message tag/component needs to be updated after ajax in order to show messages. Did you try it ?

Comment: Yes, but I mean: it's not even in the page when you inspect it. It's not there as hidden and/or blank. It's just not there. @OTM